# Why does Mathematica not return "True" for Correlation function equality expression?

Tags: proof, correlation

I wish to check the invariance property of correlation. As described in this wiki section [Wiki - Mathematical Properties of Correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#Mathematical_properties). A quote from the Wiki page I wish to test is below.

> That is, we may transform X to a + bX and transform Y to c + dY, where a, b, c, and d are constants with b, d > 0, without changing the correlation coefficient.

```
Correlation[{a + b *x1, a + b*x2}, {c + d*y1,c+ d* y2}] ==Correlation[{x1, x2}, {y1, y2}]
Refine[%, {{a, b,c, d, x1, x2, y1, y2} \[Element] Reals, {b, d} > 0}]
```

From the output, I believe I can see that these are in fact equal if I factor and cancel b and d. However, I would have hoped that Mathematica would have simply returned the result "True".

Why did Mathematica not return "True"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Correlation[{a + b x1, a + b x2}, {c + d y1, c + d y2}]==Correlation[{x1, x2}, {y1, y2}]
```

`FullSimplify`  gives the expected result:

```
Assuming[Variables[%] ∈ Reals && And @@ Thread[{b, d} > 0], FullSimplify @ %]
```

> ```
> True
> ```